Pass item from DOM by reference
I'm trying to write a subroutine which will update the value of an item from the DOM. However I can't seem to pass the item by reference.
Example code follows:
Sub Test()

Debug.Print Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(1).ColumnWidth

UpdateValue Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(1).ColumnWidth

Debug.Print Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(1).ColumnWidth

End Sub

Sub UpdateValue(ByRef dblWhat As Double)

dblWhat = 9

End Sub

The output is always 8.43, 8.43 (ie ColumnWidth has not been updated).
Is there any way to do this?
Many thanks

In that way you pass reference to memory, where value of propery is.
You can pass property value, but you can not pass property.

Can does it in this way
Sub Test()

Debug.Print Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(1).ColumnWidth

UpdateValue Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(1)

Debug.Print Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(1).ColumnWidth

End Sub

Sub UpdateValue(ByRef dblWhat As Object)

dblWhat.ColumnWidth = 9

End Sub


Thanks. However, I wanted to pass ColumnWidth as the parameter. (I am trying to write a generic subroutine which will allow various items from the DOM to be compared to an expected value passed as a second parameter and ask the user whether they want to update the value if different.)

AFAIK it cannot be done in that direct way.

If you have to compare sth. you can pass values to one subroutine and compare its, and update in other passing objects like Black cat.

Best you could do is use something like CallByName, but you'd need to pass in the column object and the property name in addition to the new value. There's no way to pass a "pointer" to something like ColumnWidth
Example:
Sub Test()
    Dim col As Range
    Set col = Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(1)
    
    Debug.Print col.ColumnWidth
    
    UpdateValue col, "ColumnWidth", 20

    Debug.Print col.ColumnWidth

End Sub

'obj  = the object being altered
'prop = the name of a property of `obj`
'vNew = the new value to set
Sub UpdateValue(obj As Object, prop As String, vNew)
    Dim curr
    
    curr = CallByName(obj, prop, VbGet) 'get the current value
    If curr <> vNew Then                'new value is different?
        If MsgBox("Update '" & prop & "' from " & curr & " to " & vNew & "?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            CallByName obj, prop, VbLet, vNew
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Thanks for all of your thoughts. In the end, I wrote a Get function and Set function which make use of CallByName and let me achieve what I wanted. Functions require more error-checking but hopefully you get the idea.
Sub Test()

If GetProperty("Columns(1).ColumnWidth") < 10 Then
    SetProperty "Columns(1).ColumnWidth", 10
End If

End Sub
Function GetProperty(strPropertyRef As String, Optional objWhich As Object) As Variant

Dim objCurrent As Object
Dim strArray() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim intLeftBracketPosition As Integer
Dim intRightBracketPosition As Integer
Dim strArrayName As String
Dim intArrayRef As Integer

If objWhich Is Nothing Then
    Set objCurrent = Application.ActiveSheet
Else
    Set objCurrent = objWhich
End If

strArray = Split(strPropertyRef, ".")

For i = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)

    If i = UBound(strArray) Then
        GetProperty = CallByName(objCurrent, strArray(i), VbGet)
    Else
        intLeftBracketPosition = InStr(strArray(i), "(")
        intRightBracketPosition = InStr(strArray(i), ")")
    
        If intLeftBracketPosition <> 0 Then
            strArrayName = Left(strArray(i), intLeftBracketPosition - 1)
            intArrayRef = Val(Mid(strArray(i), intLeftBracketPosition + 1, intRightBracketPosition - intLeftBracketPosition - 1))
            Set objCurrent = CallByName(objCurrent, strArrayName, VbGet).Item(intArrayRef)
        Else
            Set objCurrent = CallByName(objCurrent, strArray(i), VbGet)
        End If
    End If

Next

End Function
Sub SetProperty(strPropertyRef As String, varNewValue As Variant, Optional objWhich As Object)

Dim objCurrent As Object
Dim strArray() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim intLeftBracketPosition As Integer
Dim intRightBracketPosition As Integer
Dim strArrayName As String
Dim intArrayRef As Integer

If objWhich Is Nothing Then
    Set objCurrent = Application.ActiveSheet
Else
    Set objCurrent = objWhich
End If

strArray = Split(strPropertyRef, ".")

For i = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)

    If i = UBound(strArray) Then
        CallByName objCurrent, strArray(i), VbLet, varNewValue
    Else
        intLeftBracketPosition = InStr(strArray(i), "(")
        intRightBracketPosition = InStr(strArray(i), ")")
    
        If intLeftBracketPosition <> 0 Then
            strArrayName = Left(strArray(i), intLeftBracketPosition - 1)
            intArrayRef = Val(Mid(strArray(i), intLeftBracketPosition + 1, intRightBracketPosition - intLeftBracketPosition - 1))
            Set objCurrent = CallByName(objCurrent, strArrayName, VbGet).Item(intArrayRef)
        Else
            Set objCurrent = CallByName(objCurrent, strArray(i), VbGet)
        End If
    End If

Next

End Sub

